# locals in partial form- rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am running issues while rendering the partial form .

This is my new.html.haml file

```
= form_for(@lead, as: :lead, url: admin_leads_path(@lead), html: { method: :post, multipart: true }) do |f|
= render partial: "form", locals: { f: f }
    #new_lead
        = link_to 'New Lead', new_admin_lead_path, remote: true
```

I have created a new.js.erb file

```
$('#new_lead a').parent().html("<%=  j render 'form', locals: { lead: @lead }  %>")
```

I am getting this error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x0000000008bedf68>:0x00007f647bf9d760>):
 %li{style: "color: red;"}= msg
 .form-group
     = f.label :business_name
         = f.text_field :business_name, class: "form-control"
```

What should the values for locals be set in the new.js.erb file ?

Comment: The `f` from the `form_for` block isn't included in the form partial. You need to include it.

Comment: and how to include it ? @JoshBrody

Comment: $('#new_lead a').parent().html("<%=  j render 'form', locals: { f: f }  %>") Tried using this too but the error is same @JoshBrody

Comment: Thanks 
I sorted it out @JoshBrody